# How to send JSON data in cURL in PHP

Tags: php, node.js, curl, post

I have rest API of Nodejs Server, I'm trying to make a POST call to it using PHP.

My php code is:

```
function post_url($apiRoute,$data) {
    $request_url = 'http://test-app.herokuapp.com';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url . $apiRoute);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    echo $data ;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

I have tried calling this function with diff forms of data:

```
$g = array("_id" => "111");
$postapiresponse = post_url('/CCTRequest/get',json_encode($g));
```

OR

```
$postapiresponse = post_url('/CCTRequest/get',json_encode(array("_id" => "111"));
```

But on server side which Node.js, when I console log req.body I get data like this:

```
{ '{"_id":"111"}': '' }
```

How should I pass the data in PHP so I can get proper obj in node.js i.e:

```
{ '_id': '111' }
```

Comment: Dont json_encode the data manually, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS expects an array.

Comment: @castis I have tried sending array. When i send this array("_id" => "111") on server i get {} in req.body

Comment: @castis  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("_id" => "111")); tried this to. getting {} in server

Comment: please share cURL in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the PHP document:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

> **CURLOPT_POST**:
>
> > TRUE to do a regular HTTP POST. This POST is the normal
> >     **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** kind, most commonly used by HTML forms.
>
> **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS**:
>
> > If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to **multipart/form-data**.

So you can pass a query string returned by `http_build_query()` into `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`:

```
post_url('/CCTRequest/get', http_build_query($g, null, '&'));
```

and remove `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));`. (In fact, the varieble should be `$ch`, but you typed `$curl`, so this line doesn't work.)

In the other way, you can replace `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` with 
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');`, it can prevent the data be encoded automaticlly. And then send `json_encode()` data.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the code, which will prevent it setting the header `$curl` should be `$ch`:

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));`

You also need CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER uncommented.

```
function post_url($apiRoute, $data) {
    $request_url = 'www.example.com';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url . $apiRoute);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type:application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Tired your ans but no success

Comment: Can we see your node code? [Works fine in my tests](http://i.imgur.com/h1vVywv.png), but not against your herokuapp, getting `{"status":404,"content":"_id is required"}`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by using `http_build_query($g, null, '&')` for making data.

```
 $g = array("_id" => "111");
$g = http_build_query($g, null, '&');
$postapiresponse = post_url('/CCTRequest/get', $g);
```